# Hearing sound when going supersonic

Tags: acoustics, doppler-effect

Suppose we are travelling supersonic along a straight line. Further up along the line, there is a stereo, that's emitting sound at a frequency that changes in such a way that the Doppler shift caused by our supersonic travel in relation to the stereo effectively cancels out, and the sound is hence always maintained in our hearing range..

If the stereo is loud enough will we (no matter how ever briefly) be able to hear the sound at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think so. Since we don't have the source behind our backs, we will "meet" the sound and be able to hear it. When we pass the stereo, we will be able to hear the sound of the "stereo history" (i.e. already radiated) but not any "new one" (radiated post our flyby).